# How to ignore htaccess rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions, directory

I've got a problem with an application which create a wrong .htaccess in my upload folders...
The .htaccess content is:

```
<Files *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Files>
```

Can I set an .htaccess on parent folder, which overwrite the wrong one in subfolders?

Comment: No you cannot override this from parent .htaccess.

Comment: Can I write an htaccess in parent folder which deny permission to create an other htaccess in subfolders? How?

Comment: No if request comes for `http://example.com/parent/upload/file.doc` then first htaccess to operate is `/upload/.htaccess` not the parent.